# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] not working with Header

Tags: php

I have a site that allows public access to some pages, but requires a login for others. I have a link to the login from all pages, and what I'd like to do after a successful login is send the user back to the page they were on when they clicked the login link. I know the HTTP_REFERER can be spoofed, and sometimes stripped out by certain hosts and proxies, but since it's strictly within my own site, and only a convenience for users, I'm not too worried about it.

I am curious about why it isn't working in conjunction with a redirect, though. I've set a visible field to contain the value of the http referer, and it displays correctly. So the page is getting the value of the referrer variable. But when I try this:

```
$home_url =  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header('Location: ' . $home_url);
```

it doesn't work. This, on the other hand, does:

```
$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/discussions.php';
header('Location: ' . $home_url);
```

So I know the header location part works. Any idea why it doesn't want to work in conjunction with the http_referer variable?

(Also, does it drive anyone else nuts that referer is spelled incorrectly? I keep mistyping it using the OED spelling, silly me...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the login validation page, the referer will be login page, not the original one (unless you are using credentials stored in a cookie or HTTP basic/digest auth).

What you can do is, in the login page, where the user enters the details, have a hidden field with the referer of the login page request, and then pass it to the script that verifies the login and does the forwarding if the login is successful.

Better yet: since the user may not send the referer (it is configurable in most browsers), have the link to the login page include in the query string the original page. Then proceed as above, but use this value instead of the referer.

To be clear:

```
<form method="post" action="login">
...
<input name="user" type="text" />
<input name="password" type="password" />
<input name="referer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ?>" />
</form>
```

then

```
<?php
if (login_is_successful() && !empty($_POST['referer']) && !is_array($_POST['referer'])) {
    header("Location: ".urldecode($_POST['referer']));
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I just thought of that a few minutes ago, while eating dinner.

Answer (score 2):

What's the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in the first example? Is it correctly set?

You know, if you just type in the URL in the address bar, most browsers will not send the referer string.